# Writing output file is taking considerable time

Tags: python, performance

my program is taking around half a minute to create and write to 8 files, with following code.

Any suggestions to improve execution time?

```
def createFile(A,rows,filename):   
    f=open(filename,'w')
    for row in range(rows):
         f.write(*A[row])    # A is a 2D matrix with integers
    f.close()
```

Comment: Is `A` a numpy array? Then look for [np.save](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html)

Comment: Hi, please post on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. This is working code.

Comment: Take a look at `writelines` - might save you some time there too; you might want to also look at buffer/binary.

Comment: @Mustafa Aydın : Thanks.. A is a numpy array, but the output file is not binary, it has to be in readable format. Your suggestion will be helpful for binary files though.

Comment: use `np.savetext`

Comment: That might be quite good, if it's a Raspberry Pi Zero with a 5,400 rpm disk and A is large...

Comment: @sahasrara62: thanks! It has reduced the time for file creation.